# Unable to start "Debug Cortex-A8" debugger on DS-5

Tags: debugging, arm, ds-5

I am trying to start the debugger on DS-5 Ultimate Edition Version 5.26.2 which is installed on Windows 10

In debug configuration I choose EB_Cortex-A8->Bare Metal Debug->Debug Cortex-A8 with no Target configuration (no .axf specified) using connect only.

When I attempt to start the debugger (Connect to target) I get the message :

> Connection failed
>
> Unable to connect to A8.
>
> The script file ( rtsm_launcher.py ) failed during execution: Failed
>   to start model 'FVP_EB_Cortex-A8'. Please check that the model is
>   installed correctly and its installation directory is included in your
>   PATH environment variable
>
> See Target Console view for more details The script file (
>   rtsm_launcher.py ) failed during execution: Failed to start model
>   'FVP_EB_Cortex-A8'. Please check that the model is installed correctly
>   and its installation directory is included in your PATH environment
>   variable
>
> See Target Console view for more details

That is wired because I can start other debuggers like (Cortex-A9).

Is this a DS-5 problem? Or maybe a Windows 10 problem? Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Tough its a year too late, just ran into a problem like this myself and would help someone in the future.

So you are actually trying to connect to an ARM FVP( Fixed Virtual Platform), these are processor models used by ARM. If you dont have the hardware the you can use these models.

Now DS5 comes with some pre-installed FVPs, which includes Cortex A9, Arm v8 ax1 etc. But EB_Cortex-A8 is not one of them. You have to download the setup and install it separately. ARM gives you a 30 day trial license for these.

Hope this helps someone....